# How to serialize Dictionary with JsonConvert+attribute in order to hide a dictionary name?

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonconvert

I am trying to serialize this model

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Los los { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}



      public class Los
        { 
[JsonConverter(typeof(DictionaryToJsonObjectConverter))]
            public Dictionary<DateTime, List<Item>> items { get; set; }
        }


public class Item
{
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public int guests { get; set; }
    public int[] price { get; set; }
}
```

and I am getting this

```
{
    "los": {
        "items": {
            "2020-01-10T00:00:00+01:00": [
                {
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "guests": 1,
                    "price": [
                        443
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "2020-01-11T00:00:00+01:00": [
                {
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "guests": 1,
                    "price": [
                        500
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "Id": 1
}
```

and I would like to get this response

```
{
    "los": {
            "2020-01-10T00:00:00+01:00": [
                {
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "guests": 1,
                    "price": [
                        443
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "2020-01-11T00:00:00+01:00": [
                {
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "guests": 1,
                    "price": [
                        500
                    ]
                }
            ]
    },
    "Id": 1}
```

I would like to use attributes to achieve this, but I am not sure how.

I tried writing my custom json converter, but that didnt do much

```
 public class DictionaryToJsonObjectConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return typeof(IDictionary<DateTime, List<Item>>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            writer.WriteRawValue(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, Formatting.Indented));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us the code you are using to serialize if you have written any custom json converter and/or defined custom settings for serialization.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need to have extra `Los` object? Why can't you just add `public Dictionary<DateTime, List<Item>> los` property on `Rootobject`

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Actually I solved the problem by removing custom json converter and adding [JsonProperty("los")]


        public Dictionary<DateTime, List<Item>> items { get; set; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is the way how you are populating dictionary. Your current class structure is:

```
RootObject
|
|
|--los (with json proerty set to display)
    |
    |
    |--- items dictionary
```

What you need is this:

```
RootObject
|
|
|-- items dictionary los (either rename the property name to los or use JsonProperty to use los)
```

So, in order to get the required result, please emove the class Los and move the below line directly under RootObject:

```
public Dictionary<DateTime, List<Item>> items { get; set; }
```

and rename items as los.

So, after the changes, So, your Rootobject object looks like below:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    // public Los los { get; set; }
    // I don't think you need this converter unless you have special logic   
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DictionaryToJsonObjectConverter))]
    public Dictionary<DateTime, List<Item>> los { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: here is what i did to resolve the issue [JsonProperty("los")]
        //[JsonConverter(typeof(DictionaryToJsonObjectConverter))]
        public Dictionary<DateTime, List<Item>> items { get; set; }